# Scanner not working (manjaro latest release)

Tags: scanner

i have installed the "driver install" file from brother website for my brothermfcj270w printer. Installed it, printing works fine but scanner is not working. When i press the scan button on the printer it says "check connection". During installation i put both printer and scanner on same ip addresd. Sane is installed. This is all going through wi fi (usb method doesn't make the scanner work either). Any help is appreciated. Been on the forums as well.

Answer (score -1):

uncomment or add `hpaio` and `hpoj` to a new line in `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf`